# Compute $\sqrt{x} \pmod p$ working on finite fields.

Tags: modular-arithmetic, finite-fields

I was wondering about how $\sqrt{x}$ is handled while working over finite modular fields.

As we know, we cannot get decimal values while working over prime modular fields.

So for example, the operation $\frac{a}{b}$ will be computed as: $a * b^{-1} \pmod p$ NOTE: It's a modular inversion.

But which is the way of handling $\sqrt{x} \pmod p$  assuming that $x$ is a value that will give a fraction as a result as for example $x\ =\ 411$ ??

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Math Stack Exchange.  Are you asking about finding $y$ such that $y^2\equiv x\pmod p$?

Comment: I'm working on an ECC library, and I need to perform `sqrt(x)`, but the result can't obviously be decimal. So I was wondering how to handle it. And i put the example of the division and how I deal with it.

Comment: Also note if $a \in \Bbb{Q}$ has no rational square root then $\Bbb{Q}[\sqrt{a}]$ is a field extension of $\Bbb{Q}$. If $b \in \Bbb{F}_p$ has no square root in $\Bbb{F}_p$ then  $\Bbb{F}_p[\sqrt{b}]$ is a field with $p^2$ elements. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_closure

Comment: Be aware that this is a highly non-trivial task! Pocklington's algorithm in Ruben du Burck's answer is the best practical solution, because it separates out the hard case ($p\equiv 1 \bmod 8$) from the easier cases.

Answer (score 1):

You should first decide if a solution exists. This is not always the case. For example, modulo $5$ the squares are 
$$
0^2 \equiv 0 \quad 1^2 \equiv 1 \quad 2^2 \equiv 4 \quad 3^2 \equiv 4 \quad 4^2 \equiv 1
$$
so $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $\Bbb Z / 5 \Bbb Z$.

There are efficient ways to compute if $a$ is a *quadratic residue* modulo $p$. Usually one uses the *Legendre symbol* for this. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol.

Once you know there exists a solution, finding it is a whole different story. For small $p$ it may be easiest to do a brute force search. For larger values of $p$ there are known algorithms that are more efficient. See for example:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington%27s_algorithm

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm